# equivalent es6 syntax for "require('./config/passport')(passport)"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how to write this in es6?

*./server.js*

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

and how the module itself should get 'passport'?

*./config/passport.js*

```
module.exports = function(passport) {}
```

Comment: There is no "nice" syntax for it that lets you require and invoke in one go, the good end is that it's easier to analyze (the syntax).

Answer (score 1):

./server.js

```
import myFunc from 'config/passport';
myFunc(passport);
```

./config/passport.js

```
export default function (passport) {
    // Code
};
```

According to this at least:
http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html